# Dojo Datagrid "Sorry Error Occured" Issue

Tags: datagrid, dojo

My WCF service returns

```
{"Success":true,"Errors":null,"ActivityTypes":[{"id":1,"label":"Input"},{"id":2,"label":"Processing"},{"id":3,"label":"Exception Handling"},{"id":4,"label":"Quality Control"},{"id":5,"label":"Output"}]}
```

Below is the code I am using to get this into a Datagrid

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
var xhrArgs = {
    url: xhreturn,
    handleAs: "json",
    preventCache: true
}
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
deferred.then(
          function (data) {
              if (data.Success) {
                  rawdata = [data.GetActivityTypeList];
                  var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                      data: { identifier: 'id', items: rawdata }
                  });
                  var layout = [[                      
                    { 'name': 'Activity Type', 'field': 'label', 'width': '20%' }
                ]];

                  var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                      id: 'grid',
                      store: store,
                      structure: layout,
                      rowSelector: '5px'
                  },document.createElement('div'));

                  dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);
                  grid.startup();
                  standby.hide();
              }
```

I am trying to get the values returned in ActivityTypes to display in the datagrid. I keep getting "Sorry Error Occured!" instead of the data grid rendering. I replaced

```
rawdata = [data.GetActivityTypeList];
```

with this

```
rawdata = [{ "id": 1, "label": "Input" }, { "id": 2, "label": "Processing" }, { "id": 3, "label": "Exception Handling" }, { "id": 4, "label": "Quality Control" }, { "id": 5, "label": "Output"}];
```

and the datagrid works without any issues! Any help will be appreciated

Comment: does alert(data.GetActivityTypeList) return a valid object or undefined/null? If it returns undefined, you got to parse the string returned from server and then feed it to store.

Comment: Apologize, read GetActivityTypeList as ActivityTypes (as in the returned JSON). Post correction, an alert(ActivityTypes) returns

Comment: [object, Object],[object,Object],[object,Object]

Answer (score 0):

### Issue Resolved. Revised Code

`enter code here`if (data.Success) {
                      var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                          data: { items: data.ActivityTypes}
                      });
                      var layout = [[
                        { 'name': 'ID', 'field': 'id', 'width': '20%' },
                        { 'name': 'Activity Type', 'field': 'label', 'width': '80%' }

### ]];

Key was to pass data in ActivityTypes directly to the store.